# Insert %rowtype data into another table - plpgsql / Postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, rowtype

I have one table called empl, and have another table new_empl with the same columns and definition with empl. Is it possible to insert records from v_record in new_empl using the following code ?

```
DECLARE
   v_record empl%rowtype;
BEGIN 
   Insert into new_empl values v_record;
END;
```

There are too many columns in empl table and I want to avoid listing them.

Comment: No, don't avoid listing them. It is a good practice to write them and definitely worth it because this laziness  you show to avoid listing them will cost dearly, to both you as well as people who inherit your code.

Comment: Yes, the best practices do suggest that, however if your two tables have exactly the same schema and columns then it could be a easier way of solving the problem. This answer is intended for such scenario.

Comment: I think you need to limit this to either Oracle or Postgres/etc.

Comment: One way would be to `create table new_empl as select * from empl`, assuming you are yet to create `new_empl`

Comment: @KaushikNayak, the whole point is to insert from plsql variable and not from one table to another. Hope the title justifies the question :)

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible unless you use a collection of records with bulk collect. But, that isn't your question, so I don't think we can provide a solution that you want. Moreover, your title does not even say you want it for Oracle.

Comment: @KaushikNayak, Giving out vague answers was also not asked. I still insist you to read the question title again so as to understand what was asked. Thanks

Comment: I'm Sorry. I really don't understand your question and can't possible provide you a solution here.Hence, I don't know what to reply to your comment .You may wait for others, experts who could help you, if they could.

Comment: @RohitKewalramani You should always be thankful to someone who spare his/her time and atleast try to understand your problem and give solutions. I felt bad when you said `vague answers was also not asked`. I guess there was no answer was given by Kaushik as question was not clear to him. He just put a comment and comments are just to clarify his/her doubts.

Comment: @XING  trying to answer what you know is appreciated, however not other than the question asked. The comment  never sounded like a 'doubt'. And yes Thanks for your time.
Peace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above snippet would work for Oracle, but for Postgres/pgplsql, the following snippet works like a charm:

```
DECLARE
   v_record empl%rowtype;
BEGIN 
   Insert into new_empl values (v_record.*);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to insert records from v_record in new_empl using the
>   following code

`Yes` its possible however the way you are doing insert will not insert anything as nothing to assigned to the variable `v_record` . Rather you can do something like below:

```
DECLARE
   v_record empl%rowtype;
BEGIN 
   Insert into new_empl Select * from empl;
END;
```

But why you want to do it in a `PLSQL` block when you can do it `SQL` itself.

```
   Insert into new_empl select * from empl;
```

Comment: This is all together a different way of doing it. Suppose you have a rowtype variable in Plsql and want to perform an insert.

Comment: @RohitKewalramani. In that case i need to first populate the `rowtype variable` and then make an insert in loop. But in the example you showed `Insert into new_empl values v_record;` will not work atleast in Oracle. You need to map column to column even if you use `rowtype variable` . I hope i clarified your question.

Comment: the title mentions "plpgsql/postgres" and doesn't mention oracle anywhere. See that's the whole point, the 'experts' here are on a level where they oversee the question itself and then try to answer what they know without keeping any relevancy  to it. And then you say to be thankful for such ignorance :)
Peace.

Comment: @RohitKewalramani Seems you are not very much familiar with SO. Tagging question is important piece of activity so that right person with right knowledge can address it. You tagged your question to Oracle hence people here are answering with respect to Oracle. If you wanted answer from `"plpgsql/postgres"` ..remove Oracle from the tag of your question and no one with Oracle background will be able to see it. You yourself are not clear what answer you expect and from whom and blaming other experts for vague answers.  Good Luck.